# why am I getting this python syntax indexerror

Tags: python, indexing, syntax-error

I am new to python and programming in general.  I have received many syntax errors in my program.  most have been Index errors.  When I run it now what I get is:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\HW3 playing around.py", line 133, in <module>
    Main()
  File "C:\Python33\HW3 playing around.py", line 32, in Main
    EmployeeNumbers()
  File "C:\Python33\HW3 playing around.py", line 69, in EmployeeNumbers
    Sal[Index] = float(input("Enter Employee salary here: "))
IndexError: list assignment index out of range"
```

I have no idea how to solve both this error and many others that this program has, any help would be appreciated.

-Jacob

```
# Description: This program will Calculate the Average, Maximum, and Minimum Salaries of employees

#Declare Variables
EmpNum = 0
SalAVG = 0
Index = 0
SalTot = 0

# Start Main
def Main():

# Get Number of employees
    EmpNum = int(input("Enter the number of employee's here: "))
    if EmpNum <=0:
            print("Please enter positive number")

    while Index < EmpNum:

        # Call EmployeeNames
        global Name
        global Index
        global SalTot
        Name = [Index]
        EmployeeNames()

        # Call EmployeeNumbers
        global Sal
        Sal = [Index]
        EmployeeNumbers()

        # Calculate SalTot
        SalTot = SalTot + Sal[Index]

        # Increase Index
        Index = Index + 1

    # Calculate and output AVG
    SalAVG = SalTot / Index
    print("The average salary is $", SalAVG)

    # Call and output Maximum
    Maximum()
    print("The highest paid employee is ", EmpName, " With a salary of $")

    # Call and output Minimum
    global Temp
    global Switch
    Minimum
    print("The Lowest paid employee is ", EmpName, " With a salary of $")

# Arrays

# EmployeeNames array
def EmployeeNames():
    # Bind global parts
    global Name
    global Index
    # Run EmployeeNames
    Name[EmpNum] = str(input("Enter employee name here: "))

# EmployeeNumbers Array
def EmployeeNumbers():
    #Bind Global parts
    global Sal
    #Run EmployeeNumbers
    Sal[Index] = float(input("Enter Employee salary here: "))
    if Sal[EmpNum] > 200000:
        print("Please enter lower salary")
        Sal[EmpNum] = float(input("Enter Employee salary here: "))
    if Sal[EmpNum] < 0:
        print("Please enter positive number")
        Sal[EmpNum] = float(input("Enter Employee salary here: "))

# Maximum array
def Maximum():
    # Bind global parts
    global Temp
    global Switch
    global Name
    Index = 1
    Temp = 0
    Switch = 1
    while Switch > 0:
        Index = 1
        if Sal[Index] > Sal[Index + 1]:
            # Call NameSwitch
            global TempName
            global Name
            NameSwitch()
            Temp = Sal[Index]
            Sal[Index] = Sal[Index + 1]
            Sal[Index + 1] = Temp
            Switch = Switch + 1
            Index = Index + 1
        Switch = 1

# Minimum array
def Minimum():
    # Bind global parts
    global Temp
    global Switch
    global Name
    Index = 1
    Temp = 0
    Switch = 1
    while Switch > 0:
        Index = 1
        if Sal[Index] < Sal[Index + 1]:
            # Call NameSwitch
            global TempName
            global Name
            NameSwitch()
            Temp = Sal[Index]
            Sal[Index] = Sal[Index + 1]
            Sal[Index + 1] = Temp
            Switch = Switch + 1
            Index = Index + 1
        Switch = 1

# NameSwitch array
def NameSwitch():
    #Bind global parts
    global TempName
    global Name
    TempName = ""
    TempName = Name[Index]
    Name[Index] = Name[Index + 1]
    Name[Index + 1] = TempName

Main()
```

Comment: To be honest, your program has a multitude of errors and would require an extensive amount of time to fix but namely:
1)Indentation is wrong in a few sections (python is very sensitive to that) 2) you are using global variables throughout (big no-no) 3) variable naming is not python-esque

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to fix your code, but your problem can be simplified to:

```
>>> some_list = []
>>> some_list[0] = "Hello World"
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

To fix it, you need to either start the list with an initial size:

```
>>> some_list = [None]
>>> some_list[0] = "Hello World"
```

Or append to the empty list:

```
>>> some_list = []
>>> some_list.append("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your major problem stems from the use of global variables.  Instead of creating global variables, define your function with the variables as arguments like this:

```
def Maximum(Temp,Switch,Name):
```

Then call the function like this

```
Maximum(Temp,Switch,Name)
```

That way you can keep track of everything your function will need when defining it.

Back to your error, the problem is that Index is not defined in the function. recreate the function header like so:

```
def EmployeeNumbers(sal,index):
```

and in main, call it like this:

```
EmployeeNumbers(sal, index)
```

Last, define all of your variables inside main, so you do not need to pass them into main when you call it.